# Discrete approximations to $\nabla^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

I found this formula in an engineering textbook (image processing).  It is an approximation of the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) on flat space $\mathbb{R}^2$.

\begin{eqnarray*} \nabla^2 f &\approx& -20 f(\vec{x}) + 4 \big( f( \vec{x} + \epsilon \,\mathbf{i} ) + 
f( \vec{x} + \epsilon \,\mathbf{j} )
+ f( \vec{x} - \epsilon \,\mathbf{i} )
+ f( \vec{x} - \epsilon \,\mathbf{j} )\big) \\
&+& \big( f(\vec{x}+ \epsilon (\mathbf{i}+ \mathbf{j})\big)
+ \big( f(\vec{x}+ \epsilon (\mathbf{i}- \mathbf{j})\big)
+ \big( f(\vec{x}+ \epsilon (-\mathbf{i}+ \mathbf{j})\big)
+ \big( f(\vec{x}+ \epsilon (-\mathbf{i}- \mathbf{j})\big)  \end{eqnarray*}

Sorry I have no succinct way of writing this.  Typically one uses a [Stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code):

$$  \frac{1}{6\epsilon^2}  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 4 & 1 \\
4 & -20 & 4 \\
1 & 4 & 1  \end{array}  \right] $$

I suspect this falls out of [Euler MacLaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) formula.  But he also estimate the error term.  More precisely if you call the right hand side $L$ he says that:

$$  L  = \nabla^2 +  \frac{\epsilon^2}{12} \nabla^2( \nabla^2) + O(\epsilon)^4 $$

Can one formalize such an estimate using [Sobolev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) norms?

Comment: @reuns that's a good estimate as any... these engineers * *really* * wanted to know how bad the Stencil was.

Comment: $| \frac{f(x-\epsilon)-2 f(x)+f(x+\epsilon)}{\epsilon^2}-f''(x)|  = |\frac1{\epsilon^2}\int_0^{\epsilon}\int_{x-\epsilon+t}^{x+t} (f''(\tau)-f''(x))d\tau dt|$

Comment: **using Sobolev norms** Which ones? (how much smoothness do you allow, what $p$, etc.)

Comment: What about a pointwise estimate using Taylor series of each term (assuming continuous differentiability of $f$)? I wouldn't suspect anything more fancy that this.

Comment: @fedja correct. The author of this textbook does not know any analysis. But I found his estimate very interesting

Comment: One obvious observation: you need quite a smooth function for this. Even for $f\in H^5$  the formula  does not make sense because then $\Delta^2f\in H^1$ and this function is not necessarily continuous. For $f\in H^6$ the answer is clearly  yes, except it may be a little  bothersome.

Comment: @AlexGavrilov you are showing there's a problem with the textbook (whiich was written for engineers)